# how to add WinJS 4.0 to visual studio 2013 as a reference

Tags: visual-studio-2013, winjs

I am not able to add the newly downloaded WinJS 4.0 as a reference to my visual studio 2013. i already have WinJS 2.0. When i go to the add reference option and try to browse and add its looking for only (.winmd) files which is not available in the Winjs 4.0 package. 
Please help me with a step by step process.

Comment: Please answer it asap! I need it badly, can't carry on with my work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use NuGet Package Manager built-in Visual Studio to install the latest WinJS:

```
install-package WinJS
```

then I have to rewrite these files (if I'm using navigation app template) to use the new WinJS folder:

```
ui-themed.css (Windows Phone)
ui-light.css
ui-dark.css
default.html
```

Comment: thanks @Kenya-West . Well i did the first part and i got the winjs folder in my project. But still i am not getting the intellisense for Split view and Pivot.  It got partially implemented. Note:- I am using the blank app, not the navigation app so what more would i have to do?